# Writing a regex for identifying integers

Tags: regex

I want it to detect integers positive and negative, but I want it to not include the minus if it's used for subtraction.

Ex

- "29 --24 + 4" should return 29, -24 and 4
- "29 -24 + 4" should return 29, 24 and finally 4

I currently use this expression "([0-9] *-)?[0-9]+" that tests if the character after the minus isn't a number. I can then locate the actual number with another regular expression.
The problem with the one above is that it doesn't work if my number is at the start of a string. Like "-4 + 2". That will output 4 and 2.

**EDIT: The language is actionscript 3.**

Comment: so use two parts to your regexp - one for the first digit and one for the rest.

Comment: For trying out you can use this tool, http://the-regex-coach.en.softonic.com/. It is very useful for trial and error

Comment: What language are you using? What can be between numbers?

Comment: My math teacher always said there is no subtraction, there is only addition in a negative direction. Therefore `29 -- 24 + 4` should return `29, 24 and 4`.

Comment: And `29 - 24 + 4` should return `29, -24 and finally 4`. Sort of bass-ackwards from the way you got it.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:^|[-+]) *?(-?\d+)
```

http://rubular.com/r/E8WObP7HEW

Answer (score 0):

One way using `perl` flavour `regexp`:

Content of `script.pl`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

while ( <DATA> ) { 
    chomp;
    printf qq|%s = |, $_; 
    printf qq|%s |, $1 while m/(-?\d+)\s*(?:-|\+|$)/g;
    print qq|\n|;
}

__DATA__
29 --24 + 4
29 -24 + 4
-4 + 2
```

Run it like:

```
perl script.pl
```

With following output:

```
29 --24 + 4 = 29 -24 4 
29 -24 + 4 = 29 24 4 
-4 + 2 = -4 2
```

Answer (score 0):

***Actionscript:***

```
var pattern:RegExp = new RegExp("([+-]?\d+)","ig"); 
var element:Array = ut.match(pattern);
```